# Pressing 'S' for scale instead makes a dashed line with double-sided arrow pointer show up and changes the distance. How do I scale object instead?

Tags: transforms, shortcut

When I try to scale up my cube object and press the key 'S', it instead brings up a dashed line between some origin point which I'm not sure how it is determined and changes the distance between the origin point and the cube object instead of updating the scale size of the cube object. How do I fish this? Did I somehow remap how the 'S' key handles scale? I'm new to Blender.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press here on options and uncheck all checkboxes if they are checked.

[image]

and press here:

[image]

and choose "active element"

Comment: He also has the Transform pivot point (centre of header below the 'Rendering' Workspace entry) set to 3D Cursor rather than the default Median Point.

Comment: @JohnEason: You are right, i updated my answer

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer! :)

Comment: You are welcome